# Confusion about the role of capping and polyadenylation in nuclear transport

Tags: rna, transcription, mrna

Before termination stage of transcription a GMP cap is added to the 5' end and poly-A tail to 3' end of mRNA.

The link(http://sciencing.com/role-rna-polyadenylation-5434666.html) says:

> The poly(A) chain is important for transport of the mRNA from the nucleus where it is synthesized to the ribosomes where protein is translated.

I don't get this point. How does polyadenylation affcts the transportation of mRNA?

Wikipedia says abour capping's functions:

> Regulation of nuclear export;
>   Prevention of degradation by exonucleases;
>   Promotion of translation (see ribosome and translation);
>   Promotion of 5′ proximal intron excision.

I don't get how it plays a role in nuclear export.

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: Actually I read the importance of this activity but didn't understand some keypoints. I will edit it now.

Comment: @Mockingbird I really like this as a resource, I think you can start at the subheading **Key steps in mRNA processing**: http://jcs.biologists.org/content/joces/122/12/1933.full.pdf